# WPF Window.Resources - ambiguous reference

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I'm trying to add some resources to my `MainWindow.xaml` file but I cant seem to open the tag `Window.Resources` due to ambiguous reference error.

[image]

This hints to me that I have some assembly that also has the name Resources, but that is not the case, I don't have any folders/classes with that name. What could be causing that? Or rather what are the other "references" causing the compiler to be unsure which one to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Window.Resources` is an example of the special [property element syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail) that can be used in XAML.

> Specifically, the syntax begins with a left angle bracket (<),
>   followed immediately by the type name of the class or structure that
>   the property element syntax is contained within. This is followed
>   immediately by a single dot (.), then by the name of a property, then
>   by a right angle bracket (>). As with attribute syntax, **that property
>   must exist within the declared public members of the specified type**.

I've emphasized the important point that causes the error.

What you're currently doing, is trying to assign something to a property `Resources` in a type `Window` but in an instance of a `Grid`.

So you should either place your resources in the `Window` instance like this:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--your resources here-->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--your grid content here-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...or you should place your resources in the `Grid`:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--your resources here-->
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--your grid content here-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```